# Existence of slices for the action of a subgroup

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, differential-geometry

Assume that a group $G$ acts on a space $M$ in such a way that there exists a slice at a point $m \in M$. Let $H \subseteq G$ be a subgroup. Under which additional assumptions (if there are any) can one conclude that the induced action of $H$ has also a slice?

I think one could use a local section of the bundle $G \to G/H$ to construct the new slice, but the details have become somewhat messy.

I'm especially interested in this problem in the smooth category, but all input is highly welcome.

(Ps: Clearly, in the case of proper actions on a manifold one can conclude that there exists a slice for every Lie subgroup.)